# Compilation error while passing method argument to inline interface implementation

Tags: groovy

Have a look on the following Groovy code example:

```
class PersonCreator {

    static void main(String[] args) {
        println createPerson('Smith')
    }

    static createPerson(String aLastname) {
        new Person() {
            final String firstname = 'John'
            final String lastname = aLastname
        }
    }
}

interface Person {
    String getFirstname()
    String getLastname()
}
```

When I try to run it exception is thrown
`Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: aLastname for class: PersonCreator`

The exact same code runs fine with Groovy 2.3.2, but with version 2.3.3 and above it fails. Should I raise a bug in Groovy JIRA or is it a feature?

EDIT: for some reason the above example compilation with `@CompileStatic` added fails with `Error:(1, 1) Groovyc: [Static type checking] - Unimplemented node type`

Comment: just to add to the mystery: it works when adding a local var inbetween like `final xLastname = aLastname` and using this instead for the inline class

Comment: @cfrick Yup I've tried that as well. The local variable doesn't even need to be final.

Comment: could be this one https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-6811

Comment: Do you mean they may have introduced a new bug with that fix?

Comment: i have not tried to prove this (writing a test and git bisecting it would).  so it's just guesswork.  let's wait for the gurus.

Comment: In other news, overriding the accessor methods rather than the properties also works as expected (no error): `new Person() { String getFirstname() { 'John' }  String getLastname() { aLastname } }`

Comment: Updated link https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-6811